# Program C Recursion (Sum of odd numbers in array) Problem with the square of an integer

Tags: c, recursion

I have questions about a recursion function. The program is supposed to compute the sum of n odd integers and the point is each time we find the sum, we must print the following:

I need help with the print of the square for each node:

For example: If the user gives 5 numbers (1, 2, 3, 4, 5), the list will be:

1 2 3 4 5

Then it will print:

5[0] (Yes) 4[5] (Yes) 3[5] (Yes) 2[8] (No) 1[8] (No)

At first, it prints the number, after that in the [] the sum of the next odd numbers and at the end in parenthesis, a (Yes) or (No) if the number^2 in each node is greater from the sum of its next odd numbers. Like in the first one, 5>0 so it's a Yes.

I've written this so far, I can't print it though, is there anything missing?

```
int checkSumOfOdds(struct list *ptr, int sum) {
int square;

int isodd = ptr->value & 1;
square = [(struct list *) ptr->next] * [(struct list *) ptr->next];

if (isodd) sum += ptr->value;
printf("%d[%d](%s) ", ptr->value, sum, square>isodd ? "Yes":"No");
return ptr->next ? checkSumOfOdds(ptr->next, sum) : sum;
}
```

Comment: Does `square = [(struct list *) ptr->next] * [(struct list *) ptr->next];` even compile? Why the square brackets instead of parentheses? Also, you cannot multiply pointers.

Comment: Can you share the global code ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "I can't print it though" - do you get a compiler error, unexpected output, no output,...?

Comment: I've changed it to ptr->value * ptr->value; and it does compile. I still have trouble with the sum of odd numbers since it prints wrong value but I'll get there

Answer (score 0):

- The square of the value is easy:

  ```
  square = ptr->value * ptr->value;
  ```
- The comparison `square>isodd` should be `square>sum`.
- Since a recursive call is required to determine the sum, and the sum needs to be printed, the recursive call needs to be done *before* the `printf` call.
- There is no need to pass the current `sum` value as a parameter. If an odd value needs to be added to the sum, it can be done after the recursive call.
- Since the printed `sum` should not include the current value (if odd), the current value (if odd) should be added to the sum *after* the `printf` call.
- The function can be made to deal with an empty list. If `ptr` is `NULL`, just return the passed in `sum` value without printing anything. Since there is no need to pass in a `sum` value, it can just return 0 without printing anything.
- Dealing with an empty list as described above also removes the need to check `ptr->next` before deciding whether to recurse.

Here is an example implementation:

```
int checkSumOfOdds(struct list *ptr) {
    int sum;
    int square;
    int isodd;

    if (ptr == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }
    sum = checkSumOfInts(ptr->next);
    square = ptr->value * ptr->value;
    printf("%d[%d](%s) ", ptr->value, sum, square > sum ? "Yes" : "No");
    isodd = ptr->value & 1;
    if (isodd) {
        sum += ptr->value;
    }
    return sum;
}
```